# Session with Google Chrome and PHP 5.3

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-session-namespace

I have an Auth component (based on Zend_Auth) which I am using in many projects on different servers and different environments. It has always worked... until now:

When I try to log in to a new project (using the same Auth component) with **Google Chrome (12.0.742.122)**, I'm being logged out right after logging in. The problem doesn't occur with FF or IE.

Does anyone have a clue why this could be?

Comment: Interesting, What version of Chrome? Side note I do/did have issues with Chrome and JavaScript. Example on stack Chrome gives an issue with clicking the star to favorite a question, Also on github.com to watch a project wouldn't work either. Don't think it's related but just saying. But with FF and IE no problem

Comment: I've found Chrome to be quite finicky about sessions, try checking your settings for cookies under Preferences > Under the Hood > Content Settings.  An update to a newer version may have changed them some.

Comment: @Tchalvak I has nothing to do with my personal machine, all users experience this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a weird story. If you google the problem, you find that it sporadically turns up here and there but never systematically. There is a bug report for Zend Framework, there are issues at the Google Forums, there are similar reports in the tracking systems of Drupal and Wordpress. But somehow there are no clear answers.

In my case, the problem just went away by itself in the course of some other refactorings.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a ZF issue.  As strange as it may sound, the issue is solved by adding a favicon to your site.  Chrome is making a request for the favicon and invalidating the session when it gets a 404.  I read one post that suggested that a special 404 configuration might help.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this bug: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11502 - there is a fix suggested in the comments.

Comment: It's not this bug and there is no fix suggested. I wrote that myself and it was also me who wrote in the next comment that this does NOT fix the problem. :-)

Comment: I actually don't even think this is a ZF bug.

Comment: Apologies, I should have read the later comments. If you set a normal cookie with setcookie() does that disappear as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint ... I had the same problem. After debugging I found out there is a clash with cookie name on the main domain. It worked in FF and IE, Chrome however took a top domain cookie for ajax request and the lower one on regular request.